# Alterar o select na SP dá erro

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Esse é o erro:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: 'The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'TreinamentoCrudApi.Context.Cidade'. A member of the type, 'id', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.'
```

Se na SP coloco um:

`select * from tabela` --> ***funciona***

mas se faço isso:

`select nome from tabela` --> ***retorna o erro citado***

Minha model está assim:

```
public class Cidade
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Required]         
        public String nome { get; set; }
    }
```

Chamada da SP no API

```
public class GetCidade
    {
        BancoContext banco = new BancoContext();  
        public List<Cidade> GetCidades()
        {
            return banco.Database.SqlQuery<Cidade>("exec sp_cons_cidade").ToList();
        }
    }
```

Minha proc no banco executa normalmente. Como resolvo isso?

Comment: O erro está dizendo que a consulta não retorna a coluna `id` que é esperada, tente inclui-la na query.

Comment: Ao fazer `SqlQuery<Cidade>` está à espera que a SP devolva todos os campos que constituem essa classe, onde, neste caso, a coluna `id` está incluída.

Comment: Se sua model tem dois campos, você não pode retornar somente um

Answer (score 1):

Sua classe tem a propriedade id decorada como Key portanto é obrigatória. O entity espera que a query retorne todos as propriedades que não são [opcionais](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/modeling/required-optional)

No seu caso seu select tem de ser: `SELECT id, nome FROM tabela` o entity vai popular o id da classe e não vai dar erro algum.